# Trying to send a POST request to SQL server but I get an error saying "cannot insert explicit value for identity column"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

### Trying to send a POST request to my server file in order to add a class instance into an SQL database but I keep getting the following two errors:

```
Permission denied to access property "matches"
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Authors' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__208_0(Task`1 result)

         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()

         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---

         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Exec…
```

I'm not entirely sure what I can do to fix the issue as there weren't really many posts online about the issue, and the only one I've found was not very much related. Any help would be appreciated!

**The controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using blazorTestApp.Shared.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace blazorTestApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthorsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Database DB;
        public AuthorsController(Database DB)
        {
            this.DB = DB;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Post(Authors Author)
        {
            DB.Add(Author);
            await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Http service file**

```
namespace blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE
{
    public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponse<object>> POST<T>(string url, T data)
        {
            var JsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            var StringContent = new StringContent(JsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var ResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, StringContent);
            return new HttpResponse<object>(null, ResponseMessage, ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

This file simply inherits from an interface that currently only contains the post method shown. Said interface is the one that is injected into the repository

**The repository that sends the Http service**

```
namespace blazorTestApp.Client.Repositories
{
    public class AuthorsRepo
    {
        private IHttpService httpService;
        private string url = "api/Authors";
        public AuthorsRepo(IHttpService httpService)
        {
            this.httpService = httpService;
        }

        public async Task AddAuthor(Authors Author)
        {
            var response = await httpService.POST(url, Author);
            if(!response.Success)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(await response.GetBodyString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Lastly, the file calling the "AddAuthors" method**

```
@page "/Authors/Add"
@inject AuthorsRepo authorRepo
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

@code
{
    public Authors Author {get; set;} = new Authors();
    public async Task OnSubmit()
    {
        //Unrelated code
        await authorRepo.AddAuthor(Author);
        NavMan.NavigateTo("Authors");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hows your `Author` class details and Table design? Is your primary key auto incremented or you are adding manually?

Comment: As per your error details its telling that you are trying to assign a value explicitly to a column where the database automatically assigns it. Means you are trying to insert value in primary key column which is not correct. To resolve the issue either remove identity defination form that column or leave that property empty and don't pass value into it.

Comment: This seems like you have a primary key column that is auto incremented and you are trying to insert a value into it.

Comment: I get that, but how can I make it so that it does not try to insert a value into PK column?

Comment: Numerous way to handle this issue, share your class and database design or you can attached that in your question.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I haven't changed it, so I'm assuming its auto incremented

Comment: Are you using Fluent API validation or Annotations on your class? Please share for clarity.

Comment: Does your Author table as `[Key]` annotations above its Id property?

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience, it turned out that in my "Authors" class I had the "id" variable set to 1 by default rather than null/not declaring it, which interfered with the PK column. Thanks, and again, sorry

Comment: Its alright, I have posted the scenario as answer so that you can double check it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not entirely sure what I can do to fix the issue as there weren't
> really many posts online about the issue, and the only one I've found
> was not very much related.

Based on your description its appeared that

You are assigning value on your Author class primary key property which initialized values over identity column while adding new entity into your table and as its identity column which doesn't allow value assignment and consequently throwing exception which exactly, I have reproduced as following:

[image]

> In my "Authors" class I had the "id" variable set to 1 by default
> rather than null/not declaring it, which interfered with the PK column

No, you cannot set or initialize value on your Identity or Primary key column. [Primary / Identity Key properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#key-types-and-values) must always have a non-default value when adding a new entity to the context because value will be created automatically when you would insert new data into your Authors table.

Thus, Your Datable table and class should be as following:

[image]

```
public class Authors
    {
        [Key]
        public int AuthorsId { get; set; }
       
    }
```

**Note:** Do not assign or define anything on AuthorsId property if you declare it as Primary key. More you can get here in [official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations)